# urllib.quote_plus() equivalent in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, urlencode, urllib

Trying to port a snippet of code from Python:

```
my_input = "this&is£some text"
encoded_input = urllib.quote_plus(str(my_input))
```

...to JavaScript:

```
var my_input = "this&is£some text";
encoded_input = encodeURIComponent(my_input);
```

The minor difference is that `urllib.quote_plus()` will convert spaces to `+` instead of `%20` [(link)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html).
Just wondering if anyone could provide any ideas.
Currently going with this...

```
var my_input = "this&is£some text";
encoded_input = encodeURIComponent(my_input).replace(/%20/g,'+');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`urllib.quote()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) instead of `quote_plus()` in your Python code. If changing the Python code is not a solution, your choice of replacing `%20` with `+` is the preferred method anyway ([reference, second paragraph in **Description**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)).

Comment: Okay, I'll stick to what I'm doing. Accepting this because of reference link provided.